# Resize scrollview only in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-scrollview

I have an android layout made like this:

```
--------------
|   IMAGE1   | 
--------------
| SCROLLVIEW |  
--------------
|   IMAGE2   |
--------------
```

When the keyboard pops up to input text in the scrollview's edittext, it resizes the whole application. Is there any way to keep IMAGE2 at the bottom of the screen?

The layout of the application:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SignupActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/wave_2" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Logo" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="286dp"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editSurname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/surname" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCompany"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/company" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/username" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editPassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editMail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/address" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editZipCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/zipcode" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/city" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCountry"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/country" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editPhone1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/phone" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editPhone2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/mobilephone" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="signup"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/register" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

This is how actually the layout is. I want to keep the green wave image at the end of the page (under the keyboard) while still resizing the ScrollView to make it usable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji1FB.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4jcX.png

Answer (score 2):

add this lines in your manifest in activity tag  may be this works

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: adjustResize, and make sure isScrollContainer is correctly set (which it should be..): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:isScrollContainer

Comment: Not working, the layout keeps to put the bottom image just over the keyboard, like in the 2 screenshots I just added in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `IMAGE2` stuck at the bottom of the screen, put below code inside your activity tag in manifest.xml

```
<activity
       .
       . 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

EDIT:

Try to put below tag along with the above mentioned one

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Let me know if this one works for you.

Comment: Not working the way it's intended. Scrollviewd doesn't get resized, half of it still is under the soft keyboard and I can't access it.

Comment: You can try to put adjustResize along with that.

Comment: You mean "adjustPan|adjustResize" ? Same result as with "adjustPan" only.

Comment: Yes, you can use "adjustPan|adjustResize".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Button` is part of the `ScrollView`. You should pull your `Button` out of the `ScrollView` and into the parent `RelativeLayout`, changing the attributes as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //keep it to the bottom of the layout
    android:onClick="signup"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/register" />
```

Then your `ScrollView` will also need a modification:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Logo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/acceptButton" //make it stay above the button
    >
```

And given that you are using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, this should give you the correct behavior.

EDIT: Wait, if you just want the background to stay positioned, try just setting that image as your `windowBackground` in your `Activity` theme. (e.g. add `android:windowBackground="@drawable/my_background_image"` to the theme that your `Activity` uses).